# How to approach finding runtime complexity of recursive algo?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have written the code below to list all the combinations of the given array.

But I am struggling to calculate `Big-O` complexity of this recursive function.

```
public static void getCombinations(int[] input, int start,
                                   List<Integer> current,
                                   List<List<Integer>> output)
{
  output.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(current));

  if( start >= input.length )
    return;

  for(int ind=start; ind<input.length; ind++) {
    current.add(input[ind]);
    getCombinations(input, ind+1, current, output);
    current.remove(current.size()-1);
  }
}
```

Method is invoked like:

```
getCombinations(input, 0 /*start*/, current, output);
```

Sample input:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Output:

```
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[3]
```

Comment: To me it looks like you're calculating every possible subarray. So its (n choose 0) + (n choose 1) + (n choose 2) + ... + (n choose n). This work out to 2^n. Check out this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144256/sum-from-0-to-n-of-n-choose-i for a proof

Comment: I thought along the similar lines and added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking further, I think this can be written as:

```
(1) T(N)  = T(N-1) + T(N-2) + T(N-3) + .... + 1
(2) T(N-1)=          T(N-2) + T(N-3) + .... + 1
```

So, substituting (2) in (1) above,

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + T(N-1)
     = 2*T(N-1)
     = 2*(2*T(N-2)) = 2*2*T(N-2) = 2*2*2*T(N-3) etc
     = O(2^N)
```